# converting a c++ std::vector<std::string> to std::vector<unsigned char> (and vice versa)

Tags: c++, string, stl, vector, binary

Is there an easy way to convert a `std::vector<std::string>` to a `std::vector<unsigned char>` (and back again to a `std::vector<std::string>`, without having to manually convert each string and add a delimiter, such as a comma?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Please clarify your question. The former is a sequence of strings and the latter is a single sequence of characters. You will need some sort of delimiter, I imagine. Before knowing how we need to understand what you want to do. An example would be of much help.

Comment: Basically, if I wanted to convert a std::string to a std::vector<unsigned char>, I could so something like `std::vector<unsigned char> char_vec(myString.begin(), myString.end())`, right?  I was wondering if there was an easy way to convert from a std::vector<std::string> to a std::vector<unsigned char>` in a similar way.

Comment: So you really don't mean `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> >`?

Comment: This Q really needs clarification.  A string wraps an array of chars, and a vector of chars wraps an array of chars, so a conversion is possible.  But a vector of strings is acting as a 2 dimensional char array, and vector of chars is a 1 dimensional array; how can you possibly 'convert' one to the other?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: no.

The way vectors and strings are implemented are as independant, heap-allocated arrays. Therefore, you could transform `vector<string>` into `char**` (a jagged array of arrays of char), and `vector<unsigned char>` into `char*` (an array of char) when thinking about internals. This turns your problem into: is there any way to concatenate arrays without having to copy them?

No. No there is not.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<char> chars;
for (const std::string& s : strings)
{
    for (char c : s)
    {
        chars.push_back(c);
    }
    chars.push_back(',');
}
```

It's a little more clumsy without the new for loop syntax, but you get the idea.

Comment: C++ has iterators! You can write `chars.insert(chars.end(), s.begin(), s.end());`.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) should let you stuff a data structure into a sequence of `unsigned char` and reconstitute it again.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is why, and what are you trying to do?  What does the
`std::vector<std::string>` represent, and what should the semantics of
the conversion be?  If you just want to concatenate, then the simplest
solution would be something like:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> results;
for ( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = source.begin();
        iter != source.end();
        ++ iter ) {
    results.insert( results.end(), iter->begin(), iter->end() );
}
```

The implicit conversion of `char` to `unsigned char` will take care of
the reslt.

If you need to insert some sort of separator or terminator for each
string in the source, you can do that in the loop as well: for a
terminator, just append it (`push_back`) after the `insert`; for a
separator, I generally append it conditionally before the `insert`,
e.g.:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> results;
for ( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = source.begin();
        iter != source.end();
        ++ iter ) {
    if ( iter != source.begin() ) {
        results.push_back( separator );
    }
    results.insert( results.end(), iter->begin(), iter->end() );
}
```

But the question is: why `unsigned char`?  Presumably, because you are
formatting into a buffer for some specific protocol.  Is some additional
formatting required?  What is the format of a string in your protocol?
(Typically, it will be either length + data, or `'\0'` terminated.)
Does the protocol require some sort of alignment?  (For XDR—one of
the most widely used protocols—, you'd need something like:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> results;
for ( std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator iter = source.begin();
        iter != source.end();
        ++ iter ) {
    size_t len = iter->size();
    results.push_back( (len >> 24) & 0xFF );
    results.push_back( (len >> 16) & 0xFF );
    results.push_back( (len >>  8) & 0xFF );
    results.push_back( (len      ) & 0xFF );
    results.insert( results.end(), iter->begin(), iter->end() );
    while ( results.size() % 4 != 0 ) {
        results.push_back( '\0' );
    }
}
```

, for example.)